# TextView in a ConstraintLayout covers other views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm a rookie android programmer and I'm facing a problem I don't understand. I have a ConstraintLayout with a TextView (with `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`) and an EditText. The TextView's top is constrained to parent's top, the EditText's top is constrained to the TextView's bottom. Both views height are set to wrap_content. The problem is, that if I set a large text for the TextView, it fills all the ConstraintLayout a covers the EditText.

I want the TextView to grow with text, accordingly move the EditText down and if the text is so large that it won't fit available space, the EditText should be still visible and the TextView should fill all remaining space and a scrollbar should appear.

Finally, I want the TextView to be invisible (take no space) when is empty - to be shown only when I paste there some text - otherwise the EditText should be on top of the ConstraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".Holly6000MonitorFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/holly6000_font"

        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="24sp"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>




    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/light_red"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minEms="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:text="EditText"


        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/holly6000MonitorTV"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I appreciate any help :)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZuWW.png)
[But this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw6RN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#chains) in Constraint Layout to achieve this.

Simply add bottom and top chains to your TextView and EditText and change textView hieght to 0dp (Same as Match constraints):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/holly6000MonitorET"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorET"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/holly6000MonitorTV"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a few changes to your layout:

1. Add the two views to a vertical [packed chain](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain).
2. Make the chain respect the vertical constraints. If you don't do this then the *EditText* msy appear off the bottom of the screen.
3. Set the vertical bias of the *EditText* to "0.0" as follows:

   app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

   This will make sure that the *EditText* floats below the *TextView*.

That should do it. Below is a layout with these changes incorporated.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/lorem2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/holly6000MonitorET"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/holly6000MonitorET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minEms="5"
        android:text="EditText is here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/holly6000MonitorTV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TexView covers everything because its width is set to ***match parent*** and the boundaries are set to the edges of the constraint layout. You can set the widths of the Views to "***wrap content***" or can link the Views to each other with constraints like mentioned above using ***chaining.***